# Excel Index Match: If returns no result, run another index match?

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I am trying to put together a multiple index match formula.

I have columns D and E in a workbook like so:

```
Column A    Column D       Column E
A           VALUE 1        VALUE 2
B                          Value 3
```

If there is no value in column D, then i want to return the value in column E

```
=INDEX('[Phone Book for Food Specials.xls]A'!$D:$D,MATCH($A2,'[Phone Book for Food Specials.xls]A'!$A:$A,INDEX('[Phone Book for Food Specials.xls]A'!$E:$E,MATCH($A2,'[Phone Book for Food Specials.xls]A'!$A:$A,0))))
```

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Comment: You could do `=If([index match that runs on col. d]<>"",[index match that runs on col. d],[index match that runs on col. e])`